# How to output the matrix block type name in Craft? Possible feature request

Tags: matrix, block-types

Is it possible to output the block type name in Craft for each matrix block in your field?

Currently Craft just lists the name of each field within the block, but we are using generic field names (Width, depth etc), so in those instances there is no clear context for which block type is being used.

See the attached screenshot to see what I mean. I have just shown the 'Footprint' block type, but with the list of generic fields there is no way of clearly seeing this is actually 'Footprint', which can make things difficult for our client when they are managing content.

The second screenshot shows what I am trying to achieve, so it simply adds "Type: Footprint" to the start of the field list. Thanks!

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: This is definitely a feature request, it's not possible to make a modification like this to the control panel. (Even with a plugin, this may be impossible). Please post feature requests on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/106505340287442511226) or directly email support@buildwithcraft.com ([more info here](http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/83/45))

Comment: [Matrix Colors plugin for Craft CMS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-matrixcolors) would help, wouldn't it?

Comment: Great suggestion @MarionNewlevant! Ironically, I hadn't even thought of that. @JamieWade, you may also be able to work out some complex JavaScript to pull this off using the [Control Panel JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) plugin (but honestly, Marion's solution is better & far easier).

Comment: @MarionNewlevant thanks for that, I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: @Lindsey now that we know that answering the question is possible, I think we should reopen here.

Comment: Fair enough. @Marion, care to add that as an official answer?

Comment: Hmm seems like a matrix field might be overkill in this case?  Do you ever repeat the same block more than once?  Maybe just a tab of optional fields would be better?

Comment: @KeithMancuso Yeah some of the blocks can be be used more than once. Matrix was the best option because it allows the client to re-arrange the order as they please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The guys at Supercool have developed a [Craft plugin](http://plugins.supercooldesign.co.uk/plugin/pimp-my-matrix/docs) that does exactly what I was after, and as a bonus it allows you to group matrix block types which is very handy.

**UPDATE**

As of [Craft 2.3](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2615), matrix block titles are now shown as part of the core functionality, thanks P&T!

Answer (score 4):

[Matrix Colors plugin for Craft CMS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-matrixcolors) would help. It lets you assign a different color for each block type.